# Can I deactivate log shipping jobs without raising errors?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, log-shipping

I've set up log shipping from Server A to Server B.  I then set it up from B to A when B was the primary.

I've reverted back to A being primary and disabled the backup, copy and restore jobs associated with B to A shipping.  However, I have a failure of the LSAlert job on both A and B.

Is there a way to suppress these error or must I remove Log Shipping from B to A while A is primary?

My goal is to leave the log shipping configuration in place for DR, but have it not raise errors stating that databases have not been sync'd.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This normally occurs when the log-shipping is not removed cleanly. To remove the orphan entries you have to delete them from msdb logshipping tables.

```
On Primary :
delete from msdb..log_shipping_monitor_secondary
where secondary_database = '' -- secondary db name goes here 
delete from dbo.log_shipping_secondary
where primary_database='' -- primary db name goes here 

On Secondary:

delete from msdb..log_shipping_monitor_primary
where primary_database='' -- primary db name goes here 

delete from dbo.log_shipping_primary_secondaries
where secondary_database='' -- secondary db name goes here
```

Comment: My goal is to leave the log shipping configuration in place for DR, but have it not raise errors stating that databases have not been sync'd.

Comment: Use the above sql to check the logshipping tables where there are orphan entries e.g. B is primary and A is seconday --> since you have removed the logshipping, but still the logshipping tables have entries in it as they are not properly cleaned up.

Comment: I have not removed log shipping, nor do I want to.  I have only _disabled_ jobs.

Comment: If that is the case, then the logshipping alert will fail. There is no way unless you disable the alert job. Also, can you check the tables that I mentioned to see if it does not have any orphan entires